# JS Query- Global Window Object

Tags: javascript

[This code generates x is not defined](http://jsfiddle.net/yjcXe/)

```
var myobj1 = 
{  
    x:9, 
    myfunction:function()
    {
        if(this === window) 
            alert("x is not Defined");
        else if (this === myobj1)
            alert(this.x);
        else
            alert("Error!");
    }
}

function test()
{
    setTimeout(myobj1.myfunction, 1000);
}

test();
```

[Whereas this code generates x=9 as output](http://jsfiddle.net/ptZjD/)

```
var myobj1 = 
{  
    x:9, 
    myfunction:function()
    {
        if(this === window) 
            alert("x is not Defined");
        else if (this === myobj1)
            alert(this.x);
        else
            alert("Error!");
    }
}

function test()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        myobj1.myfunction()
    },  1000); 
}
```

Can someone explain me why "if callback method is not being used in test method then the global window object is being called" and "what is the significance of callback method in this case"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `myobj1.myfunction` to `setTimeout()`, it only passed the function reference.  Any connection to the object is lost.  `setTimeout()` does not have the ability to call it's function reference in context of any particular object.  Thus, you have to do it yourself by either passing your own function that will call the method in the context of the object or you can use `.bind()` in modern browsers to do the same thing.

When you do this:

```
setTimeout(myobj1.myfunction, 1000);
```

The javascript interpreter gets the function reference for `myobj1.myfunction` and passes that to `setTimeout()`.  It generates the same result as this:

```
var fn = myobj1.myfunction;
setTimeout(fn, 1000);
```

When it is passed to `setTimeout()`, it is just a function reference and called like `fn()` not in the context of any object.  Remember, a method on an object is "just" a property of the object that happens to be a function.  The `this` pointer inside a function is determined by how it is called.  If it is not called with an object context as in `myobj1.myfunction()` or explicitly called with `.apply()` or `.call()`, then the `this` pointer will not be your object.

As you've discovered, you can make your own little stub function that will call it in the context of the proper object.  In modern browsers, you can also use `.bind()` like this:

```
setTimeout(myobj1.myfunction.bind(myobj1), 1000);
```

Which essentially does the same thing as your stub function in your second code example.